# Invert match with RegExp

Tags: regex, url, yahoo-pipes

I'm currently working on a pipe on Yahoo! Pipes. I got a RegExp to match an URL. Now, I need to match the unmatched in order to delete it, so that there is only my URL. My RegExp is:

```
[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+
```

How do I invert the matching? (It has to be done via another RegExp, YPipes doesn't support any other way.)

edit: For clarification: I got a string and need to get the first URL inside of it. That's why nothing else works…

Comment: Doesn't the "not" thingy work? I.e. like this: [^(your-regexp-here)]

Comment: No, you can invert character classes that way, but not entire regexes.

Comment: Okay, thanks, my fault entirely. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo Pipes supports regex replace (use a String Regex module).

Then match the part you want to *keep* and capture it in a group. You are already doing this, although your regex itself is slightly wrong, here is one that at least has the obvious errors corrected:

```
([A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_:%&?/.=-]+)
^          ^            ^
|          |            |
|          |            + lone dashes always at the end of the character class!
|          +--- forward slashes do not need to be escaped             
+--- capturing group 1, contents later accessible through $1
```

and then replace the entire string with the contents of that group. Just put `$1` into the "replace with" field. Effectively this removes everything you did not want to keep.

Since I am not sure what your regex should actually do, I can't give you a better version.

As a general hint: Regex is always and only about *matching* stuff, and never ever about *not matching* (i.e. "excluding") stuff. There are regexes that have an excluding effect, but even they achieve it through matching.

Comment: Please read the edit. I think, another possibility would be to have the other content captured later on to support $1 again. Do you got any idea?

Comment: @FB55: Use `[\s\S]*?` before and `[\s\S]*` after the regex: `[\s\S]*?([A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_:%&?/.=-]+)[\s\S]*`